# Error with BrowserRouter in ReactJS: react.development.js:209 Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I set up my react app like this so far:

`index.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import {BrowserRouter, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Route path="/" exact component={App} />
    </BrowserRouter>
);
```

`App.js`:

```
import './App.css';
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

function App() {
  const [drinks, setDrinks] = useState([]);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/list.php?c=list');
    const jsondata = await response.json();
    console.log(jsondata.drinks);
    setDrinks(jsondata.drinks);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
    <ul>
     {drinks.map((item, index) => {
      return <li key={index}><a href="">{item.strCategory}</a></li>
     })}
    </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

But I'm getting this error in the console:

```
react.development.js:209 Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
```

I'm not sure why

Comment: What does App look like?

Comment: @morganney I just updated my question above to include `App` thanks

Comment: I don't believe the code you've shared could cause this error. The only overt issue I see if that the `Route` props are incorrect if using `react-router@6` (*there's no `component` prop in v6) and that the `Route` isn't rendered inside a `Routes` component. These would cause other ***obvious*** errors. If using RRDv5 then I don't see any issues. Please double-check your code and [edit] the post to correct any discrepancies against what you are ***actually*** running. If necessary, try to create a *running* [codesandbpx](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that we could inspect live.